# Is there a way to simulate round trip time from spring to a postgres database on localhost?

Tags: spring, postgresql

Im using Spring and a postgres database. Is there a way to simulate(create) a roundtrip time between spring and the postgres database running on localhost? That way i could create an environment similar to my production environment which would help me seeing potential performane issues earlier. For example, i have the same amount of data on localhost as i have on prod. A new feature was working perfectly(no performance issues) on localhost. Then i released it and it turned out to be really slow on production. The reason for that - as i figured out later - was that there were a lot of SQL requests happening in the background. Because the roundtrip time on prod from my spring backend to the database is way larger than the one on localhost, the performance problem only occured on prod. If i had that simulated roundtrip time on localhost i would be able to see that problem before releasing it on prod.

Comment: Your tactic should be to monitor every SQL query during development and avoid making more than several requests per method. I don't think it makes much sense testing Postgres database on localhost at all. You should not allow N+1 query to ever happen. Obviously if your application will be deployed in the same datacenter of virtual machine with Postgres then the latencies will go down. If the DB is so small that it works on the laptop, there's not much use to test in on localhost. If it's a multi-terabyte / million dollar database you should create a test environment with the same hardware.

Comment: Ye, i try to avoid N+1 requests every time now. But i faced a new problem today which is inserting multiple rows. For example if i create object A and object A has a child which is a List of object B. As far as i know its not possible to avoid N queries(if n is the size of the list) to insert(create) every single object B inside the list. The only thing i figured out i could do is using a batch. That way i dont have to send a new request(avoiding unnecessary round trip time) for every query. But im not sure whether that works as i want it to work unless i test it on a prod environment again.

Comment: The above doesnt reduce the number of sql queries. It should reduce the number of seperate requests send to the database. But because roundtrip time isnt a factor on localhost, i cant tell whether the batching works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to emulate this on the kernel level. On Linux:

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev lo root netem delay 50ms
```

This injects latency on the loopback device (localhost or 127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

[Javamelody](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody) is an awesome free open source tool that can be very easily integrated in Spring based application. It can provide you number of application/host stats in beautiful charts with extremely low overhead. It can capture time and number of each SQL, Spring services, http requests etc. You can use it in development environment to fix any performance issues. You can play around with online demo [here](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/Demo).  I have used it extensively and it's very useful.